# HyperLedger Composer: Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-embedded" for connection profile "testprofile"

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm unable to test the composer examples, the testprofile is not defined and I've no clue how to configure it for testing purposes. The below error shows that composer connector unable to determine connection profile.

```
azureuser@hyperledger101:~/.nvm/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/digitalproperty-network$ npm test

> digitalproperty-network@0.0.10 pretest /home/azureuser/.nvm/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/digitalproperty-network
> npm run lint


> digitalproperty-network@0.0.10 lint /home/azureuser/.nvm/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/digitalproperty-network
> eslint .


> digitalproperty-network@0.0.10 postlint /home/azureuser/.nvm/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/digitalproperty-network
> npm run licchk


> digitalproperty-network@0.0.10 licchk /home/azureuser/.nvm/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/digitalproperty-network
> license-check


> digitalproperty-network@0.0.10 postlicchk /home/azureuser/.nvm/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/digitalproperty-network
> npm run doc


> digitalproperty-network@0.0.10 doc /home/azureuser/.nvm/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/digitalproperty-network
> jsdoc --pedantic --recurse -c jsdoc.conf


> digitalproperty-network@0.0.10 test /home/azureuser/.nvm/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/digitalproperty-network
> mocha -t 0 --recursive



  DigitalLandTitle
    1) "before all" hook


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) DigitalLandTitle "before all" hook:
     Error: Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-embedded" for connection profile "testprofile"
      at connectionProfileStore.load.then.e (/home/azureuser/.nvm/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/composer-admin/node_modules/composer-common/lib/connectionprofilemanager.js:151:27)
```

**Environment**

Version used: composer-cli v0.9.0

Environment name and version (e.g. Chrome 39, node.js 5.4): node --version v6.9.5

Operating System and version (desktop or mobile): Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server edition.

Answer (score 0):

Update your devDependencies in package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
...
"composer-admin": "latest",
"composer-client": "latest",
"composer-connector-embedded": "latest"
}
```

and then run `npm install` and then `npm test` again.